# Can it be confirmed in this state when state transition probability >= 25%

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

if have a 2 * 2 state transition matrix, 
can it be said that if one of cell probability >= 25% then it is confirmed in this state
if it is < 25%, then it is not in this transition state

if this is wrong, how much probability is to confirm in its state

if there are 3 * 3 matrix
if one of cell probability >= 100/9 = 11.1% then it is confirmed in this state
if it is < 11.1%, then it is not in this transition state

if there are more states, this probability standard become lesser. so i guess this is not the correct way to confirm whether it is in its state.

what is the correct way to do this?

**Update: 
when i got this state transition matrix, i have to state machine diagram, how can i confirm that i should draw a line to itself or draw a line to another state, if state transition probability is greater than a standard percentage, then i draw this line, if not, then i do not draw**

Comment: What do you mean by "confirmed in this state"?

Comment: when i got this state transition matrix, i have to state machine diagram, how can i confirm that i should draw a line to itself or draw a line to another state